# `mlflow server` - Difference between `--default-artifact-root` and `--artifacts-destination`

Tags: mlflow, mlops

I am using [`mlflow server`](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#mlflow-server) to set up mlflow tracking server. `mlflow server` has 2 command options that accept artifact URI, `--default-artifact-root <URI>` and `--artifacts-destination <URI>`.

From my understanding, `--artifacts-destination` is used when the tracking server is serving the artifacts.

Based on the scenarios 4 and 5 provided by [MLflow Tracking documentation](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking.html#scenario-4-mlflow-with-remote-tracking-server-backend-and-artifact-stores)

```bash
mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://user:password@postgres:5432/mlflowdb --default-artifact-root s3://bucket_name --host remote_host --no-serve-artifacts
```

```bash
mlflow server \
  --backend-store-uri postgresql://user:password@postgres:5432/mlflowdb \
  # Artifact access is enabled through the proxy URI 'mlflow-artifacts:/',
  # giving users access to this location without having to manage credentials
  # or permissions.
  --artifacts-destination s3://bucket_name \
  --host remote_host
```

In the 2 scenarios, both `--default-artifact-root` and `--artifacts-destination` accept a s3 bucket URI, `s3://bucket_name` as the argument. I fail to see why we need 2 separate command options for setting artifact URI.

Their descriptions are

> `--default-artifact-root <URI>`
> Directory in which to store artifacts for any new experiments created. For tracking server backends that rely on SQL, this option is required in order to store artifacts. Note that this flag does not impact already-created experiments with any previous configuration of an MLflow server instance. By default, data will be logged to the mlflow-artifacts:/ uri proxy if the –serve-artifacts option is enabled. Otherwise, the default location will be ./mlruns.

> `--artifacts-destination <URI>`
> The base artifact location from which to resolve artifact upload/download/list requests (e.g. ‘s3://my-bucket’). Defaults to a local ‘./mlartifacts’ directory. This option only applies when the tracking server is configured to stream artifacts and the experiment’s artifact root location is http or mlflow-artifacts URI.

What is the reason of having the 2 command options? What happen if both are specified, will one URI precede the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first, it looks confusing because you have high flexibility. 
You can use both of them or only one of them. Let's explain it a bit more :-)

- The `--default-artifact-root` is a directory for storing artifacts for every new experiment.

  - NOTE: The default value depend if the `-serve-artifacts` is enabled or not
    (`mlflow-artifacts:/`, `./mlruns`)
- `--artifacts-destination` is used to specify the location of artifacts in HTTP requests.

  - NOTE: This option only applies when the tracking server is configured to stream artifacts (`--serve-artifacts` is enabled) AND the experiment’s artifact root location is `http` or `mlflow-artifacts URI`

**Case 1:** Use both `--default-artifact-root` & `--artifacts-destination`:

```
mlflow server
  --default-artifact-root mlflow-artifacts:/
  --artifacts-destination s3://my-root-bucket
  --host remote_host
  --serve-artifacts
```

**Case 2:** Use only `--artifacts-destination`

```
mlflow server
  --artifacts-destination s3://my-root-bucket
  --host remote_host
  --serve-artifacts
```

Case 3: Use only `--default-artifact-root`

```
mlflow server
    --default-artifact-root is s3://my-root-bucket/mlartifacts
    --serve-artifacts
```

In this case the server can resolve all the following patterns to the configured proxied object store location of `s3://my-root-bucket/mlartifacts`:

```
https://<host>:<port>/mlartifacts
http://<host>/mlartifacts
mlflow-artifacts://<host>/mlartifacts
mlflow-artifacts://<host>:<port>/mlartifacts
mlflow-artifacts:/mlartifacts
```

Answer (score 0):

however i find that when server started as artifact server, the default artifact path will overwrite destation path, which will affect experiament's default artifact path resolved;by the way, when start mlflow as a artifact server, you specify the destination path will make server as a artifact proxy, and is official recommended